# DataServiceHost

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

Is it possible use nettcp binding with DataServiceHost

Answer (score 1):

No, not without severe modification. The DataServiceHost implementation is tied to a WebHttpBinding because of the underlying dependence on REST OData based data interactions.